# Mysql JOIN (multiple) tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. 2 of them are the same (same columns, different data), and the third has some info data about other 2. Database looks like this:

Table 1:

```
+--------------+
|  ID | Name   |
+--------------+
| 1  | Table 2 |
| 2  | Table 3 |
+--------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-------------------------------+
| Name | Temperature | Pressure |
+-------------------------------+
| Table 2 |    22    | 1013     |
+-------------------------------+
```

Table 3:

```
+-------------------------------+
| Name | Temperature | Pressure |
+-------------------------------+
| Table 3 |    20    | 1009     |
+-------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to JOIN all into one table, which should look like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| Name | Temperature | Pressure |
+-------------------------------+
| Table 2 |    22    | 1013     |
| Table 3 |    20    | 1009     |
+-------------------------------+
```

Any idea how sql query should look like?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for UNION, take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864933/mysql-join-multiple-tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try union:

```
SELECT table1.name, temperature, pressure 
FROM table1 inner join table2 ON
table1.name = table2.name
UNION
SELECT table1.name, temperature, pressure 
FROM table1 inner join table3 ON
table1.name = table3.name
```

Edit:
You can make another select from those results, then you can limit, group or order:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT table1.name, temperature, pressure 
    FROM table1 inner join table2 ON
    table1.name = table2.name
    UNION
    SELECT table1.name, temperature, pressure 
    FROM table1 inner join table3 ON
    table1.name = table3.name
) as JoinedTable
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Edit 2:
To have only one row from each table (table 2 and table 3) you can use limit/group by/order by for each query (assuming you have column date):

```
SELECT table1.name, temperature, pressure 
FROM table1 inner join table2 ON
table1.name = table2.name
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
UNION
SELECT table1.name, temperature, pressure 
FROM table1 inner join table3 ON
table1.name = table3.name
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to use LIMIT in query like this (in order to get only latest entry from each table)?

Comment: Yes, all of the standard operations are possible (limit, order, group). Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for update, but is it possible to use LIMIT (and ORDER BY) to 'grab' only the latest row from Table 2 and Table 3 and then JOIN them with Table 1 just like you did in your first query?

Comment: Yes, you can use Order By, Group By, Limit in the queries that you are union joining afterwards. Check third query example.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful! Just needed to place SELECT clauses inside parentheses. Query works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) statement:

```
(
    SELECT Name, Temperature, Pressure
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name
)
UNION
(
    SELECT Name, Temperature, Pressure
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Name = Table3.Name
)
```