# Unable to union Select and Innerjoin

Tags: mysql, sql

I've hit a dilemma when developing on a system for the company and the project manage is not about!

```
SELECT clients_owner.Name, clients_owner.`number`, clients_shops.Shopname, clients_shops.PostCode, clients_shops.Location
FROM clients_shops inner join clients_owner ON
clients_owner.ShopID = clients_shops.ShopID
UNION
SELECT clients_fans.Fan
FROM clients_shops inner join clients_fans ON
clients_shops.ShopID = clients_fans.ShopID
```

The following query is returning the following error:

> 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

But using this as an example: [Mysql JOIN (multiple) tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864933/mysql-join-multiple-tables) is marked as the answer, so the queries are obviously valid. Where have I gone wrong?

Whereas the following join to merge two tables:

```
SELECT
    clients_owner.Name, clients_owner.Number, clients_shops.Shopname, clients_shops.PostCode,
    clients_shops.Location FROM clients_shops INNER JOIN clients_owner on
    clients_owner.ShopID = clients_shops.ShopID
```

Works without a hitch

Comment: `UNION` merges rows, so they have to be the same on both queries. Looks like you're trying to add another column to existing records. That should be done using `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

To use UNION you must have:

1. The same number of columns in both requests.
2. Columns in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type.

You have 5 columns in the 1-st request:

```
clients_owner.Name,
clients_owner.`number`,
clients_shops.Shopname,
clients_shops.PostCode,
clients_shops.Location
```

and 1 column in the 2-nd request:

```
clients_fans.Fan
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 2):

Union means your are adding the same columns under the existing columns you alreday have. In your case you have 5 columns in the first query and 1 in the second:

```
|1|2|3|4|5
|1|
```

doesn't match.

What you need is another join:

```
SELECT clients_owner.name,
       clients_owner.`number`,
       clients_shops.shopname,
       clients_shops.postcode,
       clients_shops.location,
       clients_fans.fan
FROM   clients_shops
       INNER JOIN clients_owner
               ON clients_owner.shopid = clients_shops.shopid
       LEFT JOIN clients_fans
              ON clients_fans.shopid = clients_shops.shopid
```

Comment: So in future.. If i wanna group another table to my query, I will follow the same route but with what join type? I eventually wanna create a view with 5+ tables

Comment: @SophieMackeral:- You can use any join but you have to make sure that if you are using UNION then **each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns**

Comment: You can _join_ together as many tables as you want.
If you have more then one fan in the clients_fans table you could also do a right join, which would give you to every shop all fans (you can get a lot of rows with those queries), and you could join them to a table where you have more information to these fans and so on...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) the number of columns in both the select statement should be equal.

**Each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns**