# How do I find Main Category name with multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
Categories

ID  PARENT_ID  NAME
1     0        Shopping
2     1        Health

Business_Categories

ID  BUSINESS_ID  CATEGORY_ID  
1    1                1
2    1                2
```

Now I want below mentioned details

BUSINESS_ID  SUBCATEGORY_NAME  MAINCATEGORY_NAME

But I don't know how could I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: That duplication has answers from old versions to the new MySQL 8 version...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql JOIN (multiple) tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864933/mysql-join-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
bus.business_id, cat2.name as subcategory_name, cat1.name as maincategory_name
from 
business_categories as bus
inner join categories as cat1 on bus.category_id = cat1.id
inner join categories as cat2 on cat1.parent_id = cat2.id
```

Comment: It returns empty result set